# get numbers with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, extract

I am trying to extract all the numbers from a page.
The page looks like this:

```
....lots of html code ....
<script>
..some code...
["listidname",[],{"list":["123456","96326478664","12345678901234"]},12]
...more code....
</script>
...even more code...
```

The amount of numbers in the list can vary, also the 12 at the end is just a random number, so this can vary as well.

what I am trying to do is extract the 123456, 96326478664 and 12345678901234.
However I am not really strong with php let alone regexes..

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $input, $output);
```

gives me the numbers, but also all the other numbers on the page...

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: do you only want the numbers wrapped by double quotes?

Comment: Use `print_r(json_decode($input))`

Comment: this is just a segment of code in a html file. I'd rather use a regex to get it straight out of their except if you could show me a way to extract the json part out of it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first extract the line and after find the numbers:

```
if (preg_match('~\["listidname",\[],\{"list":(?:[[,]"\d++")++]},\d++]~', $html, $match)) {
    preg_match_all('~"\K\d++~', $match[0] ,$result);
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to place the print_r($result) inside the if statement brackets though.

Answer (score 1):

If numbers will be in double quotes try

```
preg_match_all("/\"(\d+)\"/", $input, $output);
```